# having trouble running cronjobs for SuiteCRM in Docker container alpine

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile, alpine-linux, suitecrm

I want to get the SuiteCRM cronjobs working and if i type `crond -b -d 8` all the scheduled jobs run fine.
However if i put the command in my php Dockerfile it doesnt work (even as root).

Code of PHP Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add --update busybox-suid
COPY cronjobs /etc/crontabs/www-data
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/crontabs/www-data 

CMD ["sh", "init.sh"]

RUN crond -b -d 8
```

init.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# repair/rebuild suitecrm
./vendor/bin/robo repair:database
./vendor/bin/robo repair:rebuild-extensions
./vendor/bin/robo repair:rebuild-relationships

php-fpm
```

I cant use CMD since you can only use one CMD in the Dockerfile.
I have also tried putting `crond -b -d 8` in my init.sh but that causes Suitecrm to not build up propertly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `RUN` runs command during the image build phase and won't do you any good. The way you start processes in your container at runtime is with the `CMD` directive. If you want to show us your `init.sh` we can probably help out.

Comment: @larsks Thank you for the hint. I will edit my Post and add my init.sh

Comment: Where in your `init.sh` were you putting the cron command? What was the exact behavior when you started the container with that configuration?

Comment: @larsks I´ve put it 1 line before php-fpm. I dont get any Error regarding cron but it also doesnt work. However if i now put the same command in the console my jobs get run.

Comment: Edit2: I think I actually got it working using this: `crond -l 2 -f > /dev/stdout 2> /dev/stderr &` at the beginning of my init.sh